# jQuery: detecting if there are no rows left in table

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect if there are any rows left in a table, once none exist, I will display an alert.  The following code doesn't seem to work, any ideas? (There will be one row left with the table headers, which is why I used the index 1)

```
$('.remove_row').live('click', function() {

    //If there are no rows left in table, display alert
    if ( $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('tr:eq(1)').length == 0) {

        alert("no rows left");

    }

    $(this).parent().parent().remove();

});
```

EDIT: I tried with the remove before the alert, and it triggers every time I remove a row.

---

EDIT AGAIN: Got it, needed to make the index 2, since it is checking before the final one is actually removed from the DOM.

Comment: HTML code for context please.

Comment: Always use `===` for comparing with `0`

Answer (score 10):

```
if ( $(this).closest("tbody").find("tr").length === 0 ) {
    alert("no rows left");
}
```

This finds the cloest parent `tbody` of the clicked element (a `tbody` always exists in the DOM). It checks for the length of the `tr` elements within said `tbody`. If it equals 0, it will display the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.live()`, use `.on()` (or `.delegate()` if you are using a jQuery older than 1.7):

```
//bind to the `click` event for all `.remove_row` elements that are in the DOM or will be in the future that have the ancestor `#table-id` element
$('#table-id').on('click', '.remove_row', function () {

    var $TRs = $(this).parents('table:first').find('tr');

    //find the number of rows in the table in which the clicked `.remove_row` element is located
    if ( $TRs.length < 2) {

        alert("no rows left");

    } else {

        $TRs.eq(0).fadeOut(500, function () {

            $(this).remove();

        });

    }

});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UbUbM/

Using `.delegate()` the event binding would look like this:

```
$('#table-id').delegate('.remove_row', 'click', function () {
```

This will use your table as the root element rather than the `document` element. This also assumes that the table will be in the DOM when this code runs.

Some documentation for ya:

- `.on()`: http://api.jquery.com/on
- `.delegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/delegate
- `.live()`: http://api.jquery.com/live (Notice the note at the top about `.live()` being depreciated)